# Which cache algorithm is used in ccache?

Tags: c++, lru, ccache, mru

I was trying to find any information about cache algorithm that are used in `ccache`, but didn't find anything. So, does anyone know how `ccache` evict elements when [max_size](https://ccache.samba.org/manual.html#_configuration_settings) is reached? LRU? MRU? "Ring buffer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found in source code that ccache are using LRU: https://github.com/ccache/ccache/blob/c33cd219f85449078034ff75b54fd499549cf4e4/cleanup.c#L22